# batch file for cpu query using for /F loop

Tags: for-loop, cmd, wmic

Need help.

I am trying to run the following command on a batch file to determine if machine is Intel or AMD...

> for /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%i in ('wmic cpu get name') do set chip=%%i
>
> if "%chip%" == "Intel(R)" goto Intel else goto AMD
>
> :Intel echo this is an Intel machine
>
> :AMD echo this is an AMD machine

but I am running to an issue.  The output show as follows:

> > for /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %i in ('wmic cpu get name') do set chip=%i
>
> set chip=Intel(R)
>
> set chip=

Its showing a second chip "set" basically clearing the first result.

What do I need to input in order to have the loop stop after the first response?

Comment: Perhaps it is easier just to `findstr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first line is set, exit the loop with a GOTO.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%i IN ('wmic cpu get name') DO (
    SET "chip=%%i"
    GOTO AfterTest
)

:AfterTest

IF "%chip%" == "Intel(R)" (GOTO Intel) ELSE (GOTO AMD)

:Intel
echo this is an Intel machine
ECHO This is Intel.
GOTO AfterAll

:AMD
echo this is an AMD machine
ECHO This is not Intel.
GOTO AfterAll

:AfterAll
```

Another way to get the processor name.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%p IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command ^(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Processor^).Name.Split^(' '^)[0]') DO (
    SET "chip=%%p"
)
ECHO %chip%
```

Comment: OMG, Thank you so much.  I was breaking my head all day with this thing.  BTW... I tested it and just as a note in order for the GOTO to work I had to place them in ().  BUT Thank you Very much!!!!!!